# testing serial connections using screen

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have two usb to serial cables collected to a null modem and then the two usb connections connected two seperate usb ports on my linux machine

I want to write a program that allows them to communicate back and forth through a terminal, and wanted to test the two ports using screen

I type screen ttyUSB0 115200 but it just comes up with a blank terminal with no text, i realize i am supposed to use commands but I cant find a guide anywhere on how to use this to test to make sure the serial ports are sending/receiving data among other things, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

> I have two usb to serial cables ...

Those are not just *"cables"*, but rather adapters.
Besides the copper wire, there is an IC with a microprocessor, RAM, and ROM inside that dongle.  Your PC will recognize each USB-to-serial adapter as a (USB-based) serial port. 
IOW you have two serial ports.

Therefore you need two (not just one) instances of a terminal emulator program (e.g. `screen`), one for each serial port.

Unless you have both terminals perfectly configured, you may have confusing issues such as no echo (what you type shows up in the other terminal, but is not displayed in the terminal where you're typing), and the Enter key only responds as a new line with vertical movement of the cursor and no horizontal movement.

> I want to write a program that allows them to communicate back and forth ...

That's possible so long as you **open()** both serial terminal devices.